# I want the value of count and want to use it in other query. How is that possible?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

Here is my query:

```
$qry1 = "SELECT COUNT('name') FROM `brands` WHERE `catagory_id` = '".$id."';";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $qry1);
```

I want **the value of count and want to use it in another query**. How is that possible?

Comment: replace `COUNT('name')` to `COUNT(name)`

Comment: how will i get the value of count??  I want to store count value in a variable

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try;

```
$qry1 = "SELECT COUNT(name) as counts FROM brands WHERE catagory_id = '".$id."';";
$res = mysqli_query($conn, $qry1);
$row = mysqli_fetch_array($res);
$count = $row["counts"];
```

now this $count variable holds the value. You may include this variable in other query.

Comment: thanks @
blasteralfred

Answer (score 1):

Two steps:
1. give a meaningful name to the value calculated by `count(name)`, `total` e.g.
2. fetch first row of the result and access value from 1 using the name `total`

```
$qry1 = "SELECT COUNT(name) as total FROM `brands` WHERE `catagory_id` = '".$id."';";
$count = $mysqli->query($conn, $qry1)->fetch_object()->total;
```